# Nhibernate and MVC. Null object from query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So I am rather new to using NHibernate for database access and after studying its usage elsewhere in an application I am editing, I cannot seem to get it to work for me and I do not know why.   Effectively, I am trying to populate an object with data from my database so that I can pull pieces in and present them to the user.  The issue is that despite my syntax and code looking correct, my object remains null after query execution.

The class that is being used to represent the table in the database:

```
public class AllocateLog
{
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ResId { get; set; }
    public virtual string RequestComments { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateExited { get; set; }
    public virtual string EntryAccessPoint { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExitAccessPoint { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping code:

```
    public class AllocateLogOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<AllocateLog>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<AllocateLog> map)
    {
#if LOCAL_INSTALL
        map.Schema("dbo");
#else
        map.Schema("cred");
#endif 
        map.Table("allocate_log");
        map.CompositeId()
                    .KeyProperty(x => x.OwnerId, "owner_id")
                    .KeyProperty(x => x.MemberId, "member_id")
                    .KeyProperty(x => x.DateEntered, "date_entered");
        map.Map(x => x.UserName).Column("user_name");
        map.Map(x => x.ResId).Column("res_id");
        map.Map(x => x.RequestComments).Column("request_comments");
        map.Map(x => x.DateExited).Column("date_exited");
        map.Map(x => x.EntryAccessPoint).Column("entry_access_point");
        map.Map(x => x.ExitAccessPoint).Column("exit_access_point");
    }
}
```

The query code:

```
    public class AllocateLogsForAccessPoints : IQuery<IQueryOver<AllocateLog>, AllocateLog>
{
    private readonly string accessPoint;

    public AllocateLogsForAccessPoints(string accessPoint)
    {
        this.accessPoint = accessPoint;
    }
    public IQueryOver<AllocateLog> BuildQuery(ISession session)
    {
        return session.QueryOver<AllocateLog>()
            .Where(d => d.EntryAccessPoint == accessPoint);
    }
    public AllocateLog Execute(IQueryOver<AllocateLog> query)
    {
        return query.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And the code that I am using just as a test to see if my query will return anything to my object:

```
var asdf = DbQueryExecutor.ExecuteQuery(new AllocateLogsForAccessPoints((string)"north gate"));
```

There is only one record in the database that fits that query as it is the only row in the database with any data in entry_access_point and the string is "north gate".  The table is cred.allocate_log and all of the columns are named correctly in the mapping file.  Furthermore, removal of the mapping file or rather commenting it out does not result in any runtime error which means to me that NHibernate never even tries to use the mapping file because if I try to do this (meaning commenting out the contents of the file) with any other mapping file who's query works, I get a runtime error.  So I am entirely stumped as to why my object remains null after executing the query which runs without error.  Any ideas?  I will update my original post if you require more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue was to check the namespace and location of the various files associated with the query.  I had originally put one of the files in the wrong folder and so the namespace was mapped to that incorrect folder.  I moved the file into the correct folder but never changed the namespace.  So in the override file I had a reference to the folder the namespace said it was part of when in actuality it was not.  Correcting these errors was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might try downloading an application called NHProf from Hibernating Rhinos.  It traces all nHibernate calls and shows you exactly the SQL that nHibernate is trying to run.  It has been a godsend for me in trying to figure out just what the hell nHibernate is trying to do.

Comment: I am of course somewhat wary of downloading random items from the internet, is this what you're talking about: [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  If you are going to be using nHibernate a lot, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Well... This tool has confirmed what I thought in the first place, NHibernate is never even querying my database.  All the other queries that return successfully show up but there is never even a whisper about this one.  Seems to me like I'll have to go over to NHibernate for this one...

Comment: Great!  Glad it helped you to track it down.

Comment: While I appreciate your help Scottie, sadly that hasn't brought me to a solution.  It has allowed me to know for a fact that another piece isn't working so it technically has brought me closer.  Thanks!